# How to make cyrillic chars upper case?

Tags: php

So how do I get cyrillic chars to upper case?

```
echo strtoupper("русские");
```

this doesn't work.

Comment: this works on my localhost: 5.2.17, winXP

Comment: @k102: `strtoupper` uses your locale to determine what's alphabetic, so it can work but isn't guaranteed to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`mb_strtoupper`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) with correct encoding (without it it won't work):

```
echo mb_strtoupper("русские", "utf-8");
РУССКИЕ
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use MultiByte functions:

[**mb_strtoupper**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

Make sure that MB is installed and enabled in your PHP ;)