# php str_split() every n characters with accents

Tags: php, split, special-characters

I've this code to split a string every 3 characters, works fine, but accents are messed:

```
$splitted_array = str_split('waderòrò',3);
```

but it outputs

```
print_r($splitted_array ); >> Array ( [0] => wad [1] => er▯ [2] => ▯r▯ [3] => ▯ )
```

I know similar question was already asked, but this question didn't help me. [ucwords and french accented lettres encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012545/ucwords-and-french-accented-lettres-encoding). I did try  mb_split, but without success, because I wasn't able to find the right regex... What would be the right code?

Comment: Have you tried an array_map with the utf8-encode function?

Comment: Tried :  `function myfunction($v) {  utf8_encode ($v);}
 print_r( array_map ("myfunction",$splitted_array )`   but not working all values are empty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User "veszelovszki at gmail dot com" posted the below solution to the PHP str_split manual page. It is a multibyte-safe variation of the str_split() function.

```
function mb_str_split($string, $split_length = 1)
{
    if ($split_length == 1) {
        return preg_split("//u", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    } elseif ($split_length > 1) {
        $return_value = [];
        $string_length = mb_strlen($string, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i += $split_length) {
            $return_value[] = mb_substr($string, $i, $split_length, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $return_value;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "...so far, ...so good!" After a first testing,  seems working. "...so far,  ...so thank you!!" :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today and [here is the solution](http://ideone.com/t8GGNO) that I am using. It is basicly using regular expressions.

```
$re = '/\w{3}/u';
$str = 'waderòròцчшщ中华人民共和国';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```